# Netbeans 7.4: How can I test run php files from Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, web

How can I run the php web files directly from within netbeans to the localhost i.e. apache 2.4 on local machine?

Excuse me if this sounds very petty, but I am very new to web development and Netbeans.

Comment: Welcome to this site. You can use [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html). read especially the 'Setting up a PHP project in the NetBeans IDE for PHP' section. I hope that this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Pavel S for adding the netbeans tag and directing my query to revalent ppl.